# How to change the html inside the iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have below html where my Iframe ID is dynamically generated, now I want to change html of my span.

```
<a title="Visit Us on Google+" id="gPlus" class="addthis_button_google_plusone at300b" g:plusone:count="false">
  <div id="___plusone_0">
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
    style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 24px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 15px;"
    tabindex="0" vspace="0" id="I0_1363080003291" name="I0_1363080003291"
    src="https://plusone.google.com"
    allowtransparency="true" data-gapiattached="true" title="+1">
        <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body class="g-rba-Dh-kQa ">
                <div class="Bg" dir="ltr" id="plusone">
                <span id="widget_bounds"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td>
                <div class="ZRa">
                <span tabindex="0" role="button" title="" class="hAa Ro Bg" id="button" aria-label="Click here to publicly +1 this." aria-pressed="false"><div class="YIa"></div></span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></span></div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</a>
```

Now I want to add some value in the "title" tag using jquery

```
<div class="ZRa">
<span tabindex="0" role="button" title="" class="hAa Ro Bg" id="button" aria-label="Click here to publicly +1 this." aria-pressed="false"><div class="YIa"></div></span>
</div>
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: The Same Origin policy is in place. You cannot change the markup of a page from a different domain.

Comment: @BenM, there is no cross domain here as you html is getting rendered on your page and then you need to write some jquery function which find the iframe and changes it html, please suggest!!

Comment: But the `src` of your iframe is `plusone.google.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#___plusone_0")
    .find("iframe")
    .contents()
    .find(".hAa ")
    .attr('title', 'whatever u want');
 });
```

Comment: it is not getting changed!!

Comment: actually it seems jquery is not able to find the html which are tryign to get, any other suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#___plusone_0').find('span#button').attr('title','yourTitle');
```